# Kinect for windows program in VisualC++ can't find freeglut.dll even though freeglut has been installed. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, kinect, freeglut

This is my first post to this site. I'm hoping that someone can help me out.

I am doing some work with the Microsoft Kinect for Windows and I am trying to set up visual studio to use GLUT. The code builds successfully, but I keep getting the following error message when I try to run the program in Visual Studio:

> The program can't start because freeglut.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I have installed the Microsoft SDK and Developer Toolkit for the Kinect and I am using Visual Sutdio 2010. I followed the instructions on this tutorial, [Kinect SDK C++](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~edwardz/tutorials/kinect/kinect0.html), in order to set everything up, including downloading the freeglut 2.8.1 MSVC Package and copying the appropriate files into various folders as per the tutorial instructions. I have tried renaming freeglut.dll to glut32.dll as the tutorial suggests and leaving it unchanged.

The code I'm using is the sample code from the second page of the tutorial. I've also tried the source code provided in this tutorial: [Programming KINECT in C++ and OpenGL — Color Stream Rendering](http://pavankumarvasu.wordpress.com/programming-kinect-in-c-and-opengl-color-stream-rendering/). Both build fine, but yield the same error when run.

I tried deleting the freeGLUT files and replacing them, rearranging their folder structure in the SDK folders (and changing the corresponding filepaths in my project properties) as well as following the solution presented in this post: [compiled program cannot find freeglut.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824526/compiled-program-cannot-find-freeglut-dll). So far nothing is working and that last solution actually caused the both codes I'm using to fail building with error MSB3073.

I would appreciate any insight you might have into this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Define "installed". You did not put the DLL in one of your system directories, did you? That is never a good idea. Put it in your project's root directory and then if you run the program through MSVC, it will find it. Note that MSVC uses a different working directory when it launches your software (default is your project root - one directory up from `...\Debug\MyProgram.exe` or `...\Release\MyProgram.exe`) than the location of the output `.exe`.

Comment: @Andon Unfortunately, yes, I put the DLL in the System32 folder. Like I said, I followed the instructions on that tutorial and that's where it said to put the DLL. I've removed it now and tried moving into the project folder, but it's still not working. Specifically, I've tried putting it in Projects\MyProject, Projects\MyProject\MyProject, and Projects\MyProject\MyProject\Debug. Shouldn't one of those have been the root folder? I'm sorry if I misunderstood that, it's been a couple years since I've used Visual Studio, or done any programming in C\C++.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Okay, it seems to be working. Moving the DLL to the root folder did work. The first time I tried that I put it into an older version of the project (that I had forgotten to delete) by mistake. Fixed that, then got "Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b)" errors. Replaced all the GLUT files again to fix any file corruption, and now it works. Thanks for helping me out!